# why the page stay blank after submit form?

Tags: laravel

Hi when I submit this form it redirects me to the right page but it is blank, can I be missing something ? on one bug?, I thank anyone who can help!

**View**

```
<form class="contact" method="post" action="{{ route('sendMail') }}">
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('sendMail', $controller.'sendMail')->name('sendMail');
```

**Controller**

```php
Mail::send('emails.contacto-website', [
    'nome'     => $request->nome,
    'email'    => $request->email,
    'telefone' => $request->telefone,
    'mensagem' => $request->mensagem
], function ($messagem) use ($request) {
    $messagem->from('info@xxxx.com', 'xxxxx');
    $messagem->to('info@xxxx.com')->subject('xxxx');
});

Mail::failures();
/*  Session::flash('messagem-uk', "Message sent!");*/
return Redirect::back();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three options.

1. Using return view()

   // -- your controller code here --

   return view('your view name');
2. Using redirect

   // -- your controller code here --

   return redirect()->route('your route name');
3. Using ajax request in view

   // -- your controller code here --

   return response()->json($ret_array);

I think the third option is best if you want just send mail only in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
return redirect()->back();
```